# Search documents from MongoDB with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am trying to do a bar search to search users from a collection in MongoDB with Angular. I already did the function in the server side and it's working with Postman, but in the client side i am getting this error: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3800/api/find/: 0 Unknown Error"

this is my code on the server side

```
    function findUser(req, res) {
  let params = req.body;
  User.find(
    { 
     $or: [
             {nick : new RegExp(params.word, 'i')},
             {name : new RegExp(params.word, 'i')}
           ]
     }, function (err, docs) {
    return res.json(docs);
});
```

and the route

```
api.post('/find', md_auth.ensureAuth, UserController.findUser);
```

this is my code on the client side

user.service

```
findUser(word): Observable<any>{
        let params = JSON.stringify(word);
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('Authorization', this.getToken());
    console.log(params);
        return this._http.post(this.url+'find/', params, {headers: headers});

    }
```

user controller

```
  @ViewChild('word') wordS:ElementRef;

  findUser(){
    this.word = this.wordS.nativeElement.value;
    console.log(this.word);
    this._userService.findUser(this.word).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(this.word);
        console.log(response);
      }, error => {
        var errorMessage = <any>error;
        console.error(errorMessage);
      }
    )
  }
```

and html (view)

```
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input #word class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" (click)="findUser()" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Not related, but just wondering why you are not using `ngModel`, one of the awesome things in Angular! Instead you are accessing the dom element, which is not really needed and most of the time discouraged. Your example is simple so no harm, but you should get used to use NgModel... in my opinion :)

Comment: I would use a reactive form here. Template-forms are just messy, and like @AJT82 stated, there's no need to access the DOM directly here if you're using an Angular form.

Comment: @Brandon I do agree completely. Reactive forms can though be "scary" in the beginning, and seems to me OP is new to angular as using ngModel would be a natural thing to do and learn in the beginning. Especially if the form is this simple. But yea, Reactive forms ROCK! And sorry if I made the wrong assumption about you being new to angular, Apócrifo.

Comment: @AJT82 Agreed. Reactive Forms are one of the best features of Angular in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` doesn't return an object. It returns a string.

The server-side function is looking for a property called `word` in the request body.

If you post an object in your user.service instead of just a string...

```
...,
return this._http.post(this.url+'find/', { word: params }, headers);
```

Your function should work. However, you don't really need to call JSON.stringify if you're already passing a string to your service method.

Alternatively, if you're using a reactive form, you can just pass the `form.value` of your FormGroup instance to your service method, which will be an object, e.g. `{ word: 'some value' }`, which can then be passed as the POST data as-is.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I see what I did wrong and it's working!

Comment: You're very welcome. Always glad to help.